# Algorithm to insert a particular value into a singly linked list based on row and column

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, sparse-matrix

I'm new to **data structures**. I have been working for the past 72 hours to find an **algorithm** to insert a particular **value** into a **singly linked list** based on **row** and **column** index. I created the **singly linked list** based on the **SPARSE MATRIX** below.

[image: Image of the singly linked list based on sparse matrix]

I have attached the image of the linked list above. **For an example, if i wanted to insert a value at row 0 and column 4 with the value of 8**. What is the most suitable algorithm to make this happen ? Thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interesting point to consider.

First if you flatten your matrix, then you can notice that

- the cell at (0,1) (at row 0 and column 1) becomes the cell of index 1.
- the cell at (1,0) becomes the cell at index 5.
- More generally, the cell (i,j) becomes the cell at index **i * row_size + j**

Using this observation you can go through the list until the computed index of the cell you want to insert is smaller than the computed index of the current element.

If you know how to insert a node at a specific position in a linked list (which i recommend you try first if you dont) it should be easy to make the bridge between the two.

Comment: thanks for the answer man. But what if i want to print the linked list and display it as a sparse matrix like the sparse matrix above?

Comment: Well, that is an unrelated question right? One way to do it (although not very memory-efficient) would be to build a 'full' matrix, and then print it normally. A better (imo) solution is to print the correct number of zero and '\n' between each cell of the sparse matrix. But it is probably better to ask a separate question for that though. Anyway, if my original post answered your question you should  consider accepting it.

Comment: based on the solution u recommended, what if i need to include a value at the beginning of the linked list, i believe the algorithm to insert a node at a specific position and the beginning of the linked list is different

Comment: Not really as inserting a node at the beginning of the linked list is equivalent to inserting the node at position 0